# Help identifying/finding the part number of this piece? (maybe some kind of jackhammer?)

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I found this piece in a box of random Lego although I think it originally came from a set. It does have Lego written on the side but there is no part number. I thought it might be a jackhammer but I haven't been able to find a piece that looks like this on BrickLink or Brick Owl, maybe I was searching for the wrong thing. Does anyone know what it is/it's part number?

[image: Unknown piece]
[image: Unknown piece]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Part # 2516](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2516&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) : Minifigure, Utensil Tool Chainsaw Body with Handles and Studs

Answer (score 2):

To add to Syberion's notes, it was a part that was rather common in the mid 1980's classic space line, first appearing around the third generation of sets and themes. You don't see it as much post 2000s, but it shows up in other colors on occasion.